# Type guard with instanceof, nested if and rxjs subscription does not narrow type

Tags: typescript, rxjs, narrowing, type-narrowing

I have encountered the following situation in Typescript 4.5.5

```js
import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs";

class A {
    methodA() {}
}

class B {
    methodB() {}
}

function initialize(i: number): A | B {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
        return new A();
    }
    return new B();
}

function foo(i: number) {

    let unionType = initialize(i);
    if (unionType instanceof B) {
        if (i % 3 === 0) {
            unionType = new A();
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    const unionType$ = new BehaviorSubject<A>(unionType);

    unionType$.subscribe(_ => {
        unionType.methodA(); // TS2339: Property 'methodA' does not exist on type 'A | B'.
    });
}
```

I would assume that the type of the `unionType` variable is only `A` after the nested if is processed. This does not appear to be the case according to my IDE.

According to my quick research, this appears to fall into a whole lot of similar missunderstandings/issues with typescript:

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1719
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18498

If I understand the [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#instanceof-narrowing) correctly, the code I attempted should work.

Initially, I did not notice, that I was accessing the variable `unionType` from outside of the `subscribe` block. This is most likely a bug in my code and I should access the variable passed inside of the `BehaviourSubject`. Thank you for making me aware of this.

Regardless, I still believe, the variable type should be only `A`. Or am I completely missunderstanding, how rxjs affects variables outside of the `next` argument callback?

Comment: [Empty classes behave strangely and should be avoided](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely). Does the probably magically go away if you add a property to `B`?  If so then that's the issue and it's just a feature of structural typing, not really a bug.  If not then can please [edit] to show a more representative example.  How should we proceed here?

Comment: @jcalz interesting. In the example, I provided, adding a method to `B` does indeed solve the problem. But I encountered this in my code, where both A and B have properties. I will attempt to construct a different example, where this happens.

Comment: @jcalz I have managed to reproduce it with a setup, that matches my code better. I have updated the example given in the qeustion. Thanks to you I was made aware of the fact, that I was accessing a variable declared outside of the `subscribe` method.

Comment: Ah, there's a closure involved; this is [ms/TS#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) (and not about rxjs at all, really).  The recommended workaround is to copy the narrowed thing to a `const` whose type never changes before closing around it, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NnEA6w). Does that fully address the question? If so I will likely link this to an existing question.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thank you! this answers my question. Thanks to you I found a bug, since I never ment to access the `unionType` variable that was declared outside of the closure, and I now also understand more about the typechecking.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish, but you can get this working by organizing your code a little differently.

First I moved the rxjs out of the function because you are just going to create lots of scriptions, and I don't think this is the desired result. I then added a pipe with a `map`. From there you can use `instanceof` as you would have expected.

In the function instead of running subject we just call `next()` on the subject which was moved out of the function, and then we just pass the new class to it for the pipe to handle the rest.

It would look like this ([StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-instanceof?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts,.vscode%2Fsettings.json)):

```js
import { Subject, map } from 'rxjs';

class A { methodA() { return 'A'; } }
class B { methodB() { return 'B'; } }

function initialize(i: number) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    return new A();
  }
  return new B();
}

const unionType = new Subject<A | B>();
const unionType$ = unionType.pipe(
  map(i => {
    if (i instanceof A) {
      return i.methodA();
    }
    return i.methodB();
  })
);

function foo(i: number) {
  let value = initialize(i);
  if (value instanceof B) {
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
      value = new A();
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
  unionType.next(value);
}

const sub = unionType$.subscribe((result) => console.log(result));
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  foo(i);
}
sub.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I wasn't really looking for a way to make it work, but rather to understand what was going on. The conversation with @jcalz has cleared this up for me. The observable was never ment to contain both `A | B` and my confusion stemmed from the fact that I believed to have excluded `B` from the type, but the compiler disagreed.